# tradingview close -close[1] accuracy

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I wrote a Pine script as follow for considering RSI indicator. In this code for calculating  RSI, need to subtract closing price of the two neighboring candles (close- close[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imYwn.jpg)). As you can see in the below image the pine script close-close[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imYwn.jpg)= 0.10 while 97.42-97.31=0.11!. This difference come from what?  [image]

for calculating RMA the Pine script use sum[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imYwn.jpg) please explain how this value is computed with an example.

Let me assume we have the following closing price data for 3 days. exactly what happens has occurred for computing RSI.

[image]

```
  // @version=4

    study(title = "MyRSI", overlay=true)

   rolling_moving_average(data, length) =>
       alpha =  length 
       sum = 0.0
       for index = length to 0
          if sum == 0.0
             sum := data[index]
          else
            sum := (data[index] + (alpha - 1) * nz(sum[1]))/alpha 

    MyRSI(data, length) =>
       u = max(data - data[1], 0.0)
       d = max(data[1] - data, 0.0)
       rgain = rolling_moving_average(u,length)
       rloss = rolling_moving_average(d,length)
       rs = rgain / rloss 
       rsi = 100 - 100 / ( 1 + rs )
       rsi



    MyRmagain(data, length) =>
       u = max(data - data[1], 0.0)
       d = max(data[1] - data, 0.0)
       //rgain = rolling_moving_average(u,length)
       u  


    MyRmaloss(data, length) =>
       u = max(data - data[1], 0.0)
       d = max(data[1] - data, 0.0)
       //rloss = rolling_moving_average(d,length)
       d

    //atr2 = MyRmagain(close, 3)
    plot(MyRmagain(close, 3), title="mm[1]", color=#00FF00)
    //plot(close)
    //atr2 = MyRmaloss(close, 3)
    plot(MyRmaloss(close, 3), title="mm[1]", color=#FF0000)
    plot(close,"close",#0000FF)
    plot(close[1],"close",#ff00FF)
    //atr2 := rolling_moving_average(close, 14)
    //plot(atr2, title="EMAUP2", color=#FF00FF)

    //atr = rma(close, 14)
    //plot(atr, title="EMAUP", color=#FF00FF)
    //plot(MyRSI(close, 14))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of precision. DXY's default is two numbers after the point whereas there could be more of number after the point:

[image]

To fix thix behaviour, change the precision in the settings:
[image]

That should help.

Comment: Thank you Michel. By changing precision the first problem is solved, but other questions are still needed consideration.

Comment: RMA pine implementation is present in pine ref: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_rma there you can look at the sum calculation. And the third qustion I didn't understand.

Comment: I saw the pine ref RMA func but for better understanding this code we create an excel file with 3 closing data that can be seen in the previous post. please guide me for computing cells that marked with "?".

Comment: Suppose we have 3 data (97.35, 97.42, 97.31) from newest to oldest, respectively.  We want to compute RSI like to tradingview RSI.  For 97.31 that there is no data behind it, we have three questions 
1) How to compute close-close[1]?
2) for computing RSI we must for the first time compute this value for the oldest data or the newest data?
3) In the first computing, the SUM[1] value is =?